# replaceWith inside each don't work with my own tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have function which take text with my own tag and convert this tag to a:

```
//<link src="" title=""> -> <a href="">title</a>
function ProceedLinkTag(text) {
var items = text.filter("link");

items.each(function () {
    var currentElement = $(this);
    var title = currentElement.attr("title");
    var source = currentElement.attr("src");

    var newElement = $("<a>" + title +"</a>");
    newElement.attr("href", source);

    $(this).replaceWith("<a href='" + source + "'>" + title + "</a>"); //don't work
});
```

}

It work fine(it is detect my own tag even without close tag), I don't get any errors, but it is don't replaceWith().
Try it:

```
var text = "<link src='http://lenta.ru/' title='title'>";
ProceedLinkTag($(text));
alert(text);
```

I also try use it with close tag:

```
var text = "<link src='http://lenta.ru/' title='title'/>";
ProceedLinkTag($(text));
alert(text);
```

But it don't work too.

Comment: There are lots of syntax errors here, hard to believe this runs at all.

Comment: I am beginner in JS and JQuery. And it can be errors in it. But I run this code and don't get messages about any mistakes. Can I show me where is it?

Comment: Have you tried making the function return something?  Because it doesn't at present, your tests using `alert` are guaranteed to fail even if a replacement does occur.  The next thing that looks suspect is the argument `text`; make sure it refers to something that's a child of the document element, not an orphan or a copy where the replacement might occur but have no effect.

Comment: @sqykly, you right text is not part of document. It is plain text as you can see at examples. Who can I change it right? And you rigth with alert text(I will change it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sqykly find error:
Text in my instance was not a part of document. I change it and now it work.